# How to match media query with javascript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match string like this with regEx:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
.abv{style:value;style:value}
.xyz{style:value;style:value}

}
```

but somehow I cant.
My regEx start with `/ @media[^{]*\{ /gim`
then a want to match everything except `}}` folow by `}}`
`/@media[^{]*\{[^}}]*\}(?=})/gim` -this is not working because `[^}}] == [^}]` ... I have no idea how to make regEx working like this please help

Comment: It's not clear what you want to match exactly please update the question with the expect output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
/@media[^{]*\{(?:(?!\}\s*\}).)*/gis
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32sn6)

1. You don't need the `m` modifier, it works only on the anchors `^` and `$`
2. You meant the `s` modifier to make the `.` match also newline characters. You didn't use the `.` in your regex, but I did.
3. What you want to achieve is possible with this construct `(?:(?!\}\s*\}).)*` it means match the next character only if it is not a `}` followed by another `}` with possibly whitespace in between. This assertion is ensured by the negative lookahead `(?!\}\s*\})`. The group starting with `?:` is only a non capturing group, nothing special.

Comment: 10x for this..I missed newline characters because text is formatted onto a single line before go to this step. i Also try *? (lazy star) and it works also... /@media[^{]*\{.*?\}\}/gim;  and keep last }}.
Anyway 10x again your post was very usefull Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/src/respond.js), here is a [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qX9lT0/1)

```
@media[^\{]+\{([^\{\}]*\{[^\}\{]*\})+[^\}]+\}
```

Comment: I was looking for a regex that matches the media query container AND the content within the query itself. This returned each media query with its contents like I wanted - for anyone else reading this thread looking for the same thing.

Comment: This doesn't include the closing media query bracket

Answer (score 0):

you could also try this `/@media[^\(]+[^\)]+\){([^{]+[^}]+})+[^}]+}/ig`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@media[^\{]*\{([^\{]+\{[^\}]+\}\n*)*\n*\}
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure how this works, but it appears to (Trial and Error from Other Entries on this page)

```
/(@media[^{]*{(?:(?!}\s*}).)*}.*?})/s
```